# Multi Column Text Window Cocoa Swift NSTextView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview, multiple-columns

I want to display text in multiple columns in OS X using Cocoa.

NSTextView works well for one column, but which approach should I choose to handle multiple columns?

Any advice or hint is welcome...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to rendering text, `NSTextView` can be considered the tip of the [Cocoa Text Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextSystemArchitecture/ArchitectureOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH7-CJBJHGAG) iceberg - it's the bit you see, but there's a whole lot more going on under the surface. A multiple column layout is achieved by customizing some of these less-visible components. The link mentioned above talks specifically about how to do this in the *Common Configurations* section.